# How to get acces torrents using Transmission?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, terminal

I have installed transmission on my raspberry pi and im going to use it to download audiobooks and stuff like that. The torrent I tried to download is now in .torrent format (/.config/transmission-daemon/torrents here, don't know if this is important information). So my question is how do I get the .torrent file to the audio format. And is there a nice way to get the audio file to my phone?

Comment: Are you using this on terminal?

Comment: Yes, form my laptop with PuTTY.

Comment: Have you considered maybe looking through the help guide for Transmission? https://transmissionbt.com/help/gtk/2.9x/html/gettingstarted.html

Comment: @SiKing i followed this tutorial https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-transmission/

Answer (score 2):

.torrent file is a file which has informations about file and trackers. It is more of a download information. The easy way to download a torrent file is open that torrent file with a torrent client and the download will start. There is a gui based client called qbittorrent. If installed while you click on the torrent file the download will start after a prompt. If you are using transmission gui then you can find the same options there too.

Comment: Is Transmission not a client? I gave it a download link in the web based gui and it downloaded it. Mabey the audio file saved to another location?